# Creating a JSON User-Defined data type in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am wondering if it is possible to build a json data type in Sybase using its user defined datatype feature.

Essentially, I am considering a json to be a map where each string key points to a string, or to another map (maybe that's not a full definition of json but it captures my use case).

```
map<string,{string|map}>
```

Would this be possible? It would in a way be a self-referential data type.

Or maybe I am thinking about this wrong?

The easiest way naturally is to store the json as a plain string and leave the rest to the code that fetches the data. But I was hoping for something neater.